# Passing a URL between Pages with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a MasterDetail UI set up. On the left is a ListView. The ListView is set up like this

```
public class MasterPageList
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}

        var listOptions = new List<MasterPageList>
        {
            new MasterPageList{ Text = "Packt website", Url = "http://www.packt.com" },
            new MasterPageList{ Text = "Farmtrack Live", Url = "http://www.farmapps.co.uk" },
            new MasterPageList{ Text = "Henry Crunn", Url = "" }
        };

        // create the ListView - this is explained later in the book more fully in the What A Bind chapter

        var listView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = listOptions.ToArray()
        };

        // create the master page
        Master = new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "Webviewer",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    header, listView
                }
            }
        };
```

The ItemSelected event fires off the recipient pages

```
    void LaunchPage(object s, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var binding = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageList;

        var displayPage = new Page();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(binding.Url))
        {
            displayPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(WebviewGenerated));
        }
        else
        {
            displayPage.BindingContext = e.SelectedItem;
            displayPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Webview));
        }

        Detail = new NavigationPage(displayPage);
        IsPresented = false;
    }
```

When either of the first two ListItems are selected, the receiving ContentPage is instantiated, but the BindingContext of the page is null. I've tried a number of other methods to obtain the URL from the sending page.

From what I can see from other examples, what I am doing is correct, but the results show otherwise.

Is there something else I need to be doing to pass the URL through to the web view page?

Comment: you are setting the binding context, THEN assigning a completely new instance of the page.  Set the page instance FIRST, then set the binding context

Comment: If I have Detail.BindingContext = e.SelectedItem; BindingContext in the receiving ContentPage is still null (I've also tried swapping the order of the displayPage lines in the if/else condition - makes no difference). It looks as if the the (Page)Activator.CreateInstance is starting the new page (a break point after the displayPage = (Page) is never hit)

Comment: if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(binding.Url))
                Detail = new NavigationPage(new WebviewGenerated());
            else
                Detail = new NavigationPage(new Webview())
                {
                    BindingContext = e.SelectedItem
                }; - also gives the BindingContext = null

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
        var params = new Params {
            url = "https://www.google.com",
            querystring = ""
        };

        var secondPage = new SecondPage ();
        secondPage.BindingContext = params;
        await Navigation.PushAsync (secondPage);
```